# Developing a firefox extension that utilizes the gBrowser global variable

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xul

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [develop a firefox extension in place (not via encoding to xpi first)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13304571/develop-a-firefox-extension-in-place-not-via-encoding-to-xpi-first)

I was wondering if it's at possible to test and develop a firefox extension that utilizes the gBrowser global variable without having to compile the extension into a .xpi and load it into Firefox. Right now, in order to write code that uses gBrowser, I have to compile all my xul/js files into a .xpi file. Then I have to load this file into firefox, restart, and test. Is there an alternative method which would make debugging easier?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Dynamic Development](http://www.borngeek.com/firefox/toolbar-tutorial/chapter-4/) chapter of my toolbar tutorial. It explains how to implement a dynamic development environment that will allow you to get around having to package the extension every time (which is a real pain). You may want to peruse the [Creating the Framework](http://www.borngeek.com/firefox/toolbar-tutorial/chapter-2/) chapter first, since it lays the foundation for some of the dynamic development setup.

Comment: Worked like a charm. If you have the time, would you be able to go into how you actually figured out how that worked? I'm curious as to how you stumbled upon that method. Thanks.